# Is Heir still in Skyhold after choosing a specialisation?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm playing a rogue, and chose the *tempest* specialisation. I read that you can still talk to the other trainers after choosing a specialisation and gain some benefit from doing so.

I notice that Three-Eyes, the trainer for the *artificer* specialisation, is still present at Skyhold. Is Heir, the assassin trainer, also still at Skyhold, and if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heir, the assassin trainer is in skyhold. She is in the south east corner of the lower courtyard. Just slightly north of the stable that Blackwall is inside.

Good luck guys :)